# Why do randomNumber keep coming out the same?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, selectors-api

I'm making a lottery machine.

You want to enter a random number that is not duplicated in 6 values separately.

But why do I keep typing the same value?

please help me!

````
const oneBtn = document.querySelector(".turn");
let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 45);

number[0].textContent = randomNumber;

oneBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  number[1].textContent = randomNumber;
});

for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  console.log(randomNumber);
}```
````

Comment: because randomNumber does not keep regenerating. It is set once.  This is not a generator `let randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 45);` it just runs once. You need to run that line every time you want a random number.

Comment: @epascarello oh really thanks!!!

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks!!!!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate it on every time you want a new number.

```js
const oneBtn = document.querySelector(".turn");
const number = document.querySelectorAll(".number");


const getRandomNumber = function () {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 45);
}

number[0].textContent = getRandomNumber();

oneBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  number[1].textContent = getRandomNumber();
});

for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  console.log(getRandomNumber());
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="turn">click</button>
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
```